# Split Motion Events in android 2.3 and below

Tags: android, multi-touch

I created an app which handles multiple touches simultaneously. This works perfectly fine in android 4.0 and above.
 But when i run the same in android 2.3(having multi-touch support upto 4 touches), the app doesnt detects more than 1 touch.

Is there a way to split motions events in android 2.3.